# Could my computer be infiltrated if someone knows my external IP?

Tags: network, routing, intrusion, ip

Could my computer be compromised if someone knew my external IP? I know that when you type that in it just goes into the router page, but my computer is connected to said router.

If so, what is the attack vector? How can I protect myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your external IP isn't technically your machine's external IP, it's your router's external IP. So your machine wouldn't directly be the target of any attack: your machine doesn't **have** an external IP.

Instead, attacks would be targeted at your router. The success on that front depends on your router. Some are quite secure, some are known to be horribly broken. Search for your router's product name online to see what people have to say about it.

If your router can be broken, then the attacker could use it as a stepping-stone to get to your computer and all other computers on the network.

Another possible vector is forwarded ports. If your router is configured to forward traffic on a specific port to your computer (either manually configured by you or automatically configured through UPnP), then any attacks that use that specific port will be forwarded to your computer as well. If your computer is running a vulnerable service on that port, then that could prove problematic for you.

Comment: The first sentence is misleading and borderline incorrect. In many cases it can be correct, but it's not the rule. Actually, in my building, everybody's machine's IP is their external IP. I use the same IP assigned on my `eth0` to SSH to my home computer from my work computer.

Comment: @Adnan The question explicitly states that the IP address goes to his router. Your own personal situation is different, and therefore not applicable here.

Comment: It appears I haven't noticed that part in the question. However, I'd like to note that most home routers have a DMZ option that, when activated, exposes all ports of the DMZ host on the external IP, effectively rendering that external IP to the IP of the internal host.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn off remote management in your router and are not forwarding any ports then you won't have much of an attack vector unless there is a serious flaw in your router's firmware.  The router would prevent any traffic from getting into your computer.  Someone could potentially DDOS your router but that would only cause it to stop being able to accept new packets, they wouldn't be able to by-pass it.